# Templating service implementation with razor

Tags: c#, wcf, razor, client-server, asp.net-core

I'm looking into developing a templating service that will utilize a ASP.NET's Razor for rendering templates and writing rendered templates to the DB (ADO.NET). The request to generate a template could come as REST request (but could be something else, in general around 10 parameters will have to be passed) and applicaiton must be self-hosted (so ASP.NET WebAPI on IIS is not a choice). Also it should be in production within a month.

I've narrowed the choice down to self-hosted **WCF http service** and **ASP.NET vNext**.

Is ASP.NET vNext currently in a state that I could use it for a task like such? Could I use ADO.NET directly or go through EF? 
Is tehere any good alternative to those? Why I'm leaning towards HTTP self hosting is also the requirement for the concurrency and handling around 10 requests at a time.

Comment: FYI in asp.net 5 (vNext) in web scaffolding we are using razor as the templating lang. See the comment I just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013442/vnext-console-app-that-uses-razor-views-without-hosting#comment42680793_27013442 and here is code https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration/Program.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time of asking a question we've decided to go with MVC 5 and Owin, nowadays you could easily go with MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5 aka vNext).

The code for a console app hosted with OWIN is pretty straight forward, as you would see in many tutorials:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseAddress"]; 
            Log.Info("Listening on " + baseAddress);

            // Starts OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Log.Info("Host is being closed.");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Fatal, "Error running service: " + exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Where `Startup` is a class for OWIN middle-ware configuration. Also, normally you would host this as a windows service instead.

I can also share a controller implementation that could be used for templating service. It expects JSON data in the POST body with `TemplateEncoded` property on root of the JSON object, which contains base64-encoded string of a razor tempalte. This razor template is then rendered from the other values that are provided in request JSON. For rendering of a razor template, [RazorEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/) is used.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        dynamic model = null;
        string request = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            request = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(request);
            model.Template = RequestHelper.FromBase64(model.TemplateEncoded);

            // here you could do some validation, if required.

            var razorResult = Razor.Parse(model.Template, model);
            var result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(razorResult);

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(request, model == null ? "ERROR: template was not converted from base64 encoded string." : model.Template, ex);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but your question and conclusions are a bit unclear to me. WebAPI and MVC hosted in IIS are perfectly capable of concurrency and handling many request at a time.

Your choice of data access framework (ADO.NET versus Entity Framework) also has nothing to do with the web hosting part of your solution; you can use either in any kind of application, using any hosting environment.

So the answer is: use frameworks you are familiar with if speed of development is your main concern, as it takes away the learning curve.

Comment: Maybe questions make a little sense, I'll try to improve that. But I still have this problem to solve and without IIS. It's just that I'm trying to figure out if using vNext is even worth considering and if I can use ADO.NET directly. Probably it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is not using IIS your choice or a requirement? That's what's not clear for me. ADO.NET isn't an HTTP library, so no, you can't use that directly. Do you mean [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx), formerly ADO.NET Data Services? That's for accessing a database through Entity Framework with little logic in between.

Comment: Not using IIS is unfortunately a requirement. And I know that ADO.NET is not a HTTP library. :) Forget about that, I've figured out already that we can use System.Data.SqlClient namespace/package in vNext.